# Loading views dynamically

Tags: iphone

Case 1:

I have created View-based sample application and tried execute below code. When I press on "Job List" button it should load another view having "Back Btn" on it.

In test function, if I use

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:jbc animated:YES];
```

nothing gets loaded,

but if I use

```
[self presentModalViewController:jbc animated:YES];
```

it loads another view haveing "Back Btn" on it.

Case 2:

I did create another Navigation Based Applicaton and used

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:jbc animated:YES];
```

it worked as I wanted.

Can someone please explain why it was not working in Case 1. Does it has something to do with type of project that is selected?

```
@interface MWViewController : UIViewController {

}

-(void) test;

@end

@interface JobViewCtrl : UIViewController {

}

@end

@implementation MWViewController

(void)viewDidLoad {

UIButton* btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

btn.frame = CGRectMake(80, 170, 150, 35);

[btn setTitle:@"Job List!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(test)

      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:btn];

[super viewDidLoad]; }

-(void) test

{

JobViewCtrl* jbc = [[JobViewCtrl alloc] init];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:jbc animated:YES]; //[self presentModalViewController:jbc animated:YES];

 [jbc release];
}

(void)dealloc {

[super dealloc];

}

@end

@implementation JobViewCtrl

-(void) loadView

{

self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];

self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

UIButton* btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

btn.frame = CGRectMake(80, 170, 150, 35);

[btn setTitle:@"Back Btn!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[self.view addSubview:btn];

}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies in that in navigation based applications the parent view controller of all the new views except for modal views is UINavigationController. Which has a property navigation bar, which in turn has the property back button. Now when u push any view in a naviagtion based application a back button is displayed by default at the left of navigation bar.

Now in the view based application there is no such navigation controller as the parent view controller of ur views. In these type of application the views are added one by one on the top of the other. The top view behaves as the subview to the view beneath it. Hence no concept of navigation bar so no back button.

I am afraid how are you able to see a modal view, ( if you are not adding a navigation controller by urself, you can see if you have added any navigation controller by yourself, but then the situation would be same from this place as in my first point) in a view based application.

Thanks,

Madhup

Answer (score 0):

Firstly create your root view controller & then use push view controller...

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I came up with the same problem as you comment. And I have solved it out. Please make sure that before you use [self navigationController], it is not nil. Suppose 'self' is viewController A, then you should deal with the following:

in your app delegate, you should initialize a navigation controller like this:

```
UINavigationController *m_controller;
 m_controller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: viewController A];
```

then add the navigation controller's view to window and make it visible like this:

```
[window addSubView:m_controller.view];
```

last, remember to release m_controller.

```
[m_controller release];
```

Finally, the following code will work well :

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:jbc animated:YES];
```

Well, congratulations, the puzzle is gone.